# Datasnap server authentication problem with remote database of users credentials

Tags: delphi, authentication, datasnap, multi-tier

The situation is: Datasnap client connecting to Datasnap server with his credentials. Authentication procedure starts with server makes a request to remote database which holds users credentials. If credentials matches - all good, authentication is done. But what if remote database is unavailable at this moment? How can i push to client something like "Server is not available at the moment, try again later" while authenticating? Or second case: the user is blocked (to realize this we need to access database too) and i want to tell him a reason why he can't access to service? I was googling this issue, but i still don't understand the right way to do it.

Any tip can be helpful, thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DSAuthenticationManager.OnUserAuthenticate` event can only return `True` or `False`, and if it returns `False`, the exception that is raised at the client is predetermined.

One solution to this is to have your `OnUserAuthenticate` always return a `True` value, then in your client, call a servermethod of your own design, that returns a message that you have coded as appropriate for the situation it found. I return my message as a `var` parameter to the servermethod.

Comment: I won't let you log in, and won't tell you why - Datasnap authentication technologies.

Comment: It is strange that the authentication mechanism cannot return the reason why access is denied. Your decision is clear. It seems that you have to do something like that. Thank you.

Comment: I am happy to help.